# How do I save authenticated user in a cookie in django?

Tags: python, django, cookies

Here's a snippet of my code :

```
class LoginView(View):
    facility = 'unique-named-facility'
    audience = {'broadcast':True}
    form_class = LoginForm
    #This is a constructor
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        #Initialize inherited parent calss by calling its constructor
        super(LoginView,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        #Create an instance of redis publisher at the time od instaniation of Login View 
        self.redis_publisher = RedisPublisher(facility=self.facility, **self.audience)


    def get(self, request):
        #Create a message ovject for websocket
        message = RedisMessage('A message has been passed to all clients listening to this unique-named-facility')
        #Publish the socket
        self.redis_publisher.publish_message(message)
        #Initialize the login form
        form = self.form_class()
        #Render the login form
        if request.COOKIES.get('user') != None:
            login(request,request.COOKIES.get('user'))
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/app/dashboard/')
        return render(request,'login/index.html',{'form' : form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            #Fetch username and password
            user_name = form.cleaned_data["user_name"]
            password = form.cleaned_data["password"]
            remember_me = form.cleaned_data["remember"]
            #Authenticate the User
            user = authenticate(username=user_name, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                #After authentication login the user
                login(request,user)
                # Redirect to the new page if authenticated succesfully
                response = HttpResponseRedirect('/app/dashboard/')
                if remember_me:
                    response.set_cookie('user',user)
                return response
            else:
                # Empty previous form Content
                form = self.form_class()
        # If user is still not autheticated re render the view with warning message
        return render(request,'login/index.html',{'form' : form , "warning": "Please enter valid credentials"})
```

Also the screenshot of the browser return an error regarding pk :
[image]

What I am trying to implement here is a twitter like functionality of remember me (Keep me logged in) through django 1.10

Comment: Instead of posting screenshots of text, *post the text*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is happening here: [https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.10.x/django/contrib/auth/**init**.py#L101](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.10.x/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py#L101)

in `user.pk` is `user` not a user object but a str object. and underlying problem is apparently that you are redefining `str` somewhere in your code as a variable or/and as a result, you are passing a string object to `login()` instead of a user object

check where it is and fix it